# Fetch fields starting with 2 particular substring in mongodb using springboot?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to find all the documents with first name starting with Ram or Shyam.
I tried the following which actually worked in mongoDb

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      name: {
        $regex: "^Ram"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": {
        "$regex": "^Shyam"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

I got around count of 4k documents with this find.

Now when I tried to convert this mongo shell query into java.
Things do work but only name starting with Shyam get filtered. As a result the count also decreases to 2k.

Can someone please look at the below code and tell me why is it happening?
Why things are working in mongodb and not in java.

Java Equivalent Code --

```
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("Friends");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("Friend");
        BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject("$or", Arrays.asList
            (new BasicDBObject("name", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "^Ram")).append("name", new 
             BasicDBObject("$regex", "^Shyam"))));
        collection.find(filter).forEach((Consumer<Document>) doc -> {
                 // some java function
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out. There is just one some thing as $or operator always take array
In my java code I have converted it into array but just forgot that there is no need to append .

The solution will be --

```
BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject("$or", Arrays.asList
            (new BasicDBObject("name", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "^Ram")),new BasicDbObject("name", new 
             BasicDBObject("$regex", "^Shyam"))));
        collection.find(filter).forEach((Consumer<Document>) doc -> {
                 // some java function
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your mongo query, you need to match against `name` field but not on `id` field. That's the mistake

```
BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject("$or", Arrays.asList
    (new BasicDBObject("name", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "^Ram"))
    .append("id", new //Here is the mistake
           BasicDBObject("$regex", "^Shyam"))));
```

It should be

```
    BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject("$or", Arrays.asList
        (new BasicDBObject("name", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "^Ram"))
       .append("name", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "^Shyam"))));
```

Comment: Oh sorry my bad @Gibbs I must edit the question. In my java code I have wrote name.... accidentally typed id here...
Also recently observed one thing ...that only the last append is filtering ..it means if I add one more append then only that will be filtered out.

Don't know why is this happening ...